# How to use Cycle.js without Browserify/Webpack?

Tags: cyclejs

**Bower**: I couldn't find a Bower package for @Cycle/Core, @Cycle/DOM, do these libraries exist? I'm confused at why there is an NPM package in the first place since Cycle.js is front-end based (and NPM is specialized for back-end only).

**ES5**: Is it possible to use Cycle.js with Gulp/Typescript/ES5 (and not use Browserify/webpack)?

Comment: NPM is not for back-end only. See Frederik's link in his answer or Google it. Some developers suggest not using Bower at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything Frederik said, plus here is a standalone Cycle.js example on codepen. You can see the links to the JavaScript files being loaded by clicking on Settings, then JavaScript. Here they are for convenience:

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.js
https://rawgit.com/cyclejs/cycle-core/master/dist/cycle.js
https://rawgit.com/cyclejs/cycle-dom/master/dist/cycle-dom.js`

Full example is on [codepen](http://codepen.io/foxdonut/pen/gaExZy?editors=101)

Answer (score 3):

*npm* is not specialized for back-end only. It is for everything.[1](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging)

It is possible to use *Cycle.js* without *browserify* or *webpack*. The library comes with ES5 distribution files, found in the *dist* directory.

Yes, you can use *Gulp*, *TypeScript* and ES5 with *Cycle.js*.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try [stealjs](https://github.com/stealjs/steal/).

At runtime it downloads your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I use npm to get the packages, gulp to move the packages to wwwroot.  TypeScript to downcompile, and systemjs to load the modules.  No webpack or bower required.